# WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a video grabber, the grabber must parse protected content using the chrome driver.
I tested the grabber on a local server, everything works, but on the server it gives the following error.

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.1.0) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/fastuser/data/www/z-time.zone/grabber/browser_video.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in init
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in init
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I fixed this part of the problem using these commands:

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (2.1.0) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
```

This is what I entered into the command line.

```
pip install requests
pip3 install requests
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade requests
pip3 install requests -U
```

Can you help me with this part of the code? I can’t figure out if this is a problem in the grabber itself or if the conflict is happening directly on the server.

```
File "/var/www/fastuser/data/www/z-time.zone/grabber/browser_video.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 115, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(f"Service {self._path} unexpectedly exited. Status code was: {return_code}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```